# IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE not working as it should

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

I am trying to turn a PNG image with a white box to a green box. The background of the PNG is transparent.

I have written out code but it doesn't work for some reason. I have looked and tried a lot of things and i cannot see anything wrong with the code.

Thanks

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 255, 0, 100);
imagesavealpha($image, TRUE);
imagepng($image, $save_filename);
```

The image gets exported still with a white box. Will IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE not work with white?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. To anyone in the future...

I added

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
```

Before image_filter(